# How to add multiple modal images using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I currently have 2 images that I want the user to be able to click on and have it popup, but so far only one image is working. I know that both images have the same id, but when I try changing the id's I have to create new CSS code, etc.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption { 
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
                <img id="myImg" src="img/roof.jpg" alt=" Riga, Latvia" width="300" height="200">
                <img id="myImg" src="img/personal.jpg" alt=" Riga, Latvia" width="300" height="200">
                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                
                <!-- The Close Button -->
                <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

                <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

                <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
                <div id="caption"></div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set class for the elements

```
<img id="myImg" class="imageClass" src="img/roof.jpg" alt=" Riga, Latvia" width="300" height="200">
<img id="myImg" class="imageClass" src="img/personal.jpg" alt=" Riga, Latvia" width="300" height="200">
```

and use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("imageClass")
```

get collection of the img elements. Then apply the following on each element as below.

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("imageClass");
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    var img = images[i];
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        modalImg.alt = this.alt;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isnt common or adviceable to use the same `ID` more then once.
Look at this website about `CSS` `id's` and `classes`.
[ids and classes](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Try to use the name element or the class element so you dont have to change/copy your CSS.
`document.getElementByName` or `document.getElementByClassName` should do the trick.

Comment: So in my situation how can I make it so both of these pictures have the same functions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've given them both the same id, just like you said, two elements can't have the same id and the whole problem where you mention that it's to do with css is exactly what classes are for.

Try changing your code to this:

JS:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img1 = document.getElementById('myImg1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('myImg2');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

img1.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText1.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

img2.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

CSS:

```
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
.modalImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.modalImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption { 
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
            <!-- The Close Button -->
            <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

            <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

            <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
            <div id="caption"></div>
            </div>
```

Admittedly my edits are very basic but I just tried to get your code working, you can probably clean it up quite a lot. So here i've just given both images the same class styling (instead of id) and given them two different variable assignments and click events in the javascript.

Notice how both the images now have different IDs as well (ID's have to be unique, classes can be shared).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/djL2gxyu/

Hope this helps.